# How to add more than one action to same controller in zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to add 'addAction' and '**deleteAction**' for existing controller.here I used zendframework-ZendSkeletonApplication-zf-release-2.0.3, I add these 2 action in IndexController and also I created 2 pages for each action within the `index` folder. but how it add to the `module.config.php` this is the code my module.config.php file

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),                    
                ),

                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

please help me.

Comment: Can't you add another route to the `module.config.php` above?

Comment: please can you show me that @DavidWeinraub

Comment: actually i add another 2 routes, after that only works last route. @DavidWeinraub

Comment: Sometimes, the order of the routes matters. I think you need to add them from most-specific (ex: `/somecontroller/:id/edit` and `/somecontroller/:id/delete`) to least-specific (ex: `somecontroller/:id`)

Comment: @Sam's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134163/131824) does a great job of handling this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample Route configuration i use in my project, where everything is based off of the root path `/`

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'kz' => array(
            'type'    => 'literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Kennzahlen\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'add' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'add',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'add'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'edit' => array(
                    'type' => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'edit',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'edit'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```

The first route named `kz` has the basePath `/`

After that you have two separate child-routes called `add`  and `edit` who append the base-path with either add or edit, so the full route for them become `/add` and `/edit`

Please consider checking [the online Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) for further clarification on your questions regarding routing, as that really is a great place to start.

Alternatively you may also want to check out [DASPRiDs Router Presentation](http://stuff.dasprids.de/slides/zendcon2012/introducing-the-new-zend-framework-2-router/presentation.html#1) from ZendCon